# Loading Data to Variable Height Table in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET to create a web app. JS, JQuery, CSS, and HTML are being used. New to web dev, so if you have some good resources to read, they would be appreciated.

I am using Google Maps API to plot some locations. I have created a sidebar which I would like to list nearby properties (eventually click-able). Here are my two concerns:

1) How can I load all properties? Currently my code only displays the first one. The following JS code only lists the last location. In HTML I am using the following label:

```
<label id ="SidebarLabelName"></label>
```

In JS:

```
for (i = properties.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var displayNum = i + 1;
    SidebarLabelName.text(displayNum + ")  " + properties[i]);
}
```

2) How do I create a table that has a variable number of rows? For example, if I have 10 properties I want to show on my sidepane, then I want 10 rows. I would also like to have pages; if I have 30 properties to list, 26 items on the first page (google maps api limits alpha characters to label markers), 4 on the next.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**:
The code you have overwrites the text in SidebarLabelName for each property, thats why you see only the last property. This can be fixed by following code:

```
var allprops = "";
for (i = properties.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var displayNum = i + 1;
    allprops = allprops + "(" + displayNum + ")  " + properties[i]);
}
SidebarLabelName.text(allprops);
```

**Question 2**:
One of the ways to sovle this is to use the same approach as above:

HTMLCode

```
<div id ="tableDiv"></div>
```

and JS code:

```
var allpropRows = "";
for (i = properties.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var displayNum = i + 1;
    allpropRows = allpropRows + "<tr> <td> (" + displayNum + ")  " + properties[i] + "</td> </tr>");
}
tableDiv.html( "<table>" + allpropRows + "</table>");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help Naresh. However, the solution for Q1 didn't quite work. If I hardcode a string in allprops, it displays, but it will not display the correct string for all props with the properties inside. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3723204, I've never worked with Google Maps API, so, I'm not sure what kind of properties does it return. Being said that I have assumed **properties** array in your code is an array of strings. So, if any of the **properties[i]** returns an object type, then you may see unintended behavior. This explanation may not solve your problem, but I guess it may give you an idea.